# WPF add header to ListBox so it scrolls like DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, listbox, scroll

I'm trying to create a layout that uses a `ListBox` and my custom header that looks like a ruler, but for dates (with explicit start and end dates).  The goal is to have an appearance and feel similar to a `DataGrid`, except that the column header row would be replaced by my `DateTape` object.  When the user scrolls horizontally, the `DateTape` and `ListBox` both scroll, but when the user scrolls vertically, only the `ListBox` scrolls and the `DateTape` stays at the top (like the column header row in the `DataGrid`).

So far, the best I've been able to do is as follows:

```
    <Window x:Class="ProjectNS.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ProjectNS"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="600">
        <Window.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
                <my:CustomRectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="File" />
            </Menu>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <DockPanel>
                    <my:DateTape DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <my:DateTape.Dates>
                            <CalendarDateRange Start="10/4/2011" End="11/4/2011" />
                        </my:DateTape.Dates>
                    </my:DateTape>
                    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
    </Window>
```

The only problem I have with this solution is that the vertical scrollbar for the `ListBox` is at the extreme right of the control which means the user has to scroll horizontally to make the scrollbar appear.  I need the scrollbar visible at all times.

I tried placing the `DateTape` and `ListBox` into a `ScrollViewer`, but then the `DateTape` scrolls out of view when scrolling vertically.

FYI - My `CustomRectangle` object is a `UserControl` that allows the user to adjust the horizontal position and width real-time to position it as desired in line with the `DateTape`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up having to restructure a bit.  The `ListBox` is now an `ItemsControl` nested within a `ScrollViewer` with the vertical scroll bar hidden (not disabled).  I also have an independent `ScrollBar` docked to the right side that is tied to the vertical scroll bar in the `ScrollViewer` in the code-behind.  This handles the vertical scrolling.  Finally, a secondary `ScrollViewer` contains the `DateTape` and the `ItemsControl` set to handle the horizontal scrolling.

XAML

```
    <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File" />
        </Menu>
        <ScrollBar x:Name="verticalScrollBar"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                   SmallChange="1"
                   LargeChange="3"
                   Scroll="verticalScrollBar_Scroll"
                   SizeChanged="verticalScrollBar_SizeChanged"
                   Style="{StaticResource scrollBarHiderStyle}"
                   Maximum="{Binding ElementName=listScroller, Path=ScrollableHeight}" />
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="dateScroller"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <my:DateTape x:Name="dateTape"
                             DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             Dates="{Binding Source={StaticResource dateRange}}" />
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="listScroller" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="{x:Null}" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsList"
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
```

C#

```
        // this function merely sets the scroll bar thumb size
        private void verticalScrollBar_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            verticalScrollBar.Track.ViewportSize = itemsList.ActualHeight / 2;
        }

        // this function links the scroll bar to the scrollviewer
        private void verticalScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            listScroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
        }
```

I tried to tie the independent `ScrollBar` to the scroll bar in the `ItemsControl` through use of a `ItemsPanelTemplate`, but I couldn't get that to work.